# Why is the length/values field "1, 'C', 'P'" returning error #1064 in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin

I'm in a bit of a pickle here. I'm doing an assignment for class using phpMyAdmin, where I was given the tables and I'm just entering the data and creating simple relationships, nothing difficult. I'm having trouble with the syntax on one of the entries, though. I want to create a column named Dealer_Type of the type CHAR with a length of 1 and the values 'C' and 'P', with the default value being 'C'. The entry in the instructions is as so:

```
Field Name: Dealer_Type 
Data Type: CHAR(1) 
Values: “C” for commercial, “P" for private 
Default Value: “C”
Index: --- 
AI: no
NULL: no
```

I [filled it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPfB4.png) exactly as the [docx of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pgga.png)  instructs (no ERD given, all in Word), and received the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', 'C', 'P') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'C' ) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 1
```

I followed the instructions/syntax to the best of my understanding, filling the length/values field with `1, 'C', 'P'`, which is where MySQL runs into the #1064 error, as per the error message. As someone else mentioned, I cannot fill the length/values field this way, but I just can't seem to find the proper documentation or anything similar to my question online on how to properly fill the field to accomplish what I'm looking to do. I searched around phpMyAdmin and MySQL questions alike, different phrasing for my issue, and the specific SQL error, and found only vaguely useful information. There is no assigned textbook.

I know how to use Workbench, so I could just create it using a script, but I must be missing something here, and I'd like to figure it out. What is the proper syntax to set the column length to 1 while also defining the only acceptable values as 'C' and 'P' using the phpMyAdmin GUI? Thank you so much for taking the time in advance.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: The error message reports with SQL code that is declaring a column but the start of the error string doesn't belong in a column declaration & looks like what you put in a field so you are probably abusing the field. Plus what are that 1 & 2 letters doing together anyway? But SQL Workbench--which you should have put in a tag---documentation is easily found.

Comment: What SQL statement are you running? That's not shown in your question.

Comment: No self-written SQL statement. I'm supposed to use the UI to create the table in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: But now you are not clearly reflecting that you had the 1 & 2 chars in a field--per an image you had before whose content you no longer mention. I do see that you put them in a heading but that doesn't clearly show exactly what you did. (If you're using a gui, it's reasonable to give an image to augment a text description of the fields.) It's exacly the issue in my last comment. Also what "PDF"? PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: The `1` needs quoting: `'1'` like the other `CHARs`.

Comment: Yet again: Put the relevant instructions in your post as text not image/link. The only image needed for this is the filled-in form but you should also describe it in words.

Answer (score 0):

it's to do specifically with the length/values line (I did recently use PHPmyadmin). the length value requires one integer value only as far as I can tell. there is no way around it and perhaps using the bool value instead along with a script to output true as "P" and false as "C". according to your teachers instructions it doesn't need that kind of validation check anyways (from what I can see). hope this helps. I am willing to elaborate if need be.

Comment: No way around what? What bool value? What kind of validation check?

Answer (score -1):

I'll explain it to you I guess. bool is a 1 or 0 value (good for choosing between two things).

A validation check is a check on some data within a Database which determines if a user made a user error. (foreign keys are an example of a validation check). your teacher has not as far as I know of asked you for this specific check but if you HAVE to have it be either one of these two characters (which is not possible through pure SQL in PHPmyadmin) and it HAS to be validated you'll have to either use PHP or CSV and some csv parser. YOU DON'T HAVE TO DO THIS as far as I know of. to fix it just remove the "P" and the "C" from the length value and assume the user knows how to put in data.

Comment: Please don't post two answers, click on 'edit' below the first one  to edit it & click on 'delete' below this one to  delete this one. But your writing still isn't clear about how you are using your tools.